# "No connection could be made" error when following basic mongo install instructions

Tags: mongodb

I am new to MongoDB and would like to set it up on my local pc - without making connections to any external server or device. I'm running windows 8 and have followed these basic instructions (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/), which can be summarized as:

1. download appropriate build
2. install appropriate build
3. make db folder
4. run mongo.exe

After the fourth step above I'm running into this error:

C:\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\bin>mongo.exe
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.6
connecting to: test
2014-12-13T11:15:19.061-0500 warning: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:10061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
2014-12-13T11:15:19.061-0500 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:146exception: connect failed

Could anyone help me understand what's going on here? I think this may be a pretty basic question but I'm not seeing answers out there so maybe other people are running into the same problem. The mongo tutorial that I used (with the link given above) talks about a Security Alert dialog box potentially popping up if there is a network privacy issue but I'm not seeing that at any point in the process. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Before running `mongo.exe` which is the client. You need to start the `mongod` instance which acts as the server. Invoke `mongod.exe` and then connect to it by invoking `mongo.exe`.

Comment: Yep duplication, sorry about that. Thanks for your help though.